# Медленная загрузка файлов на сервер

Tags: php, apache, веб-сервер

Есть PHP форма отправки файлов на сервер. При загрузке файлов на сервер с ПК, скорость загрузки нормальная и все файлы успешно загружаются. Однако, загрузка не работает на телефоне, даже подключенном к Вай-Фаю. Не могу понять в чем проблема. Не подскажите?
Веб-сервер Apache

HTML форма:

```
<form id="add_user_info" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" novalidate>
    <div>
        <h3>Фото:</h3>
        <input id="driver_photo" type="file" name="user_photo" placeholder="Добавьте фото">
    </div>

    <div class="multi_photos multi1">
        <h3>Фото паспорта:</h3>
        <input type="file" name="user_passport_photo[]" placeholder="Добавьте фото" required>
        <div id="minus" class="minus1"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
    </div>
    <div class="multi_photos multi2">
        <h3>Фото водительских прав:</h3>
        <input type="file" name="voditel_prava[]" placeholder="Добавьте фото" required>
         <div id="minus" class="minus2"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" name="add_driver_by_editor" class="btn add_user_info">Добавить</button>
</form>
```

Пример кода:

```
    $user_photo = $_FILES['user_photo'];
    $file_path = $user_photo['tmp_name'];
    $path = 'images/' . basename($user_photo['name']);
    move_uploaded_file($file_path, $path);

    mkdir($one_driver_path . '/passport', 0777, true);
    for($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['user_passport_photo']['name']); $i++) {
        $path_tmp = $one_driver_path . '/passport' . '/' . basename($_FILES['user_passport_photo']['name'][$i]);
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['user_passport_photo']['tmp_name'][$i], $path_tmp) )
    }
```

Comment: мб в телефоне или вайфае?

Comment: Пробовал с разных телефонов, с Вай Фая, 3Г. Результат один и тот же.

Comment: ну `move_uploaded_file` тут вообще не при делах. этот метод предназначен для перемещения уже загруженного файла из временной директории туда, куда вам надо. Возможно имеет смысл указать,какой у вас вэб-сервер.

Comment: Каким образом? Объясните, пожалуйста.

Comment: в вопросе написать,что за вэб-сервер, apache или IIS вы используете, или еще что. Ибо принимает файл сервер, а не пхп.

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: можно пример кода?

Comment: Добавил в вопрос

Comment: на телефонах точно никаких там антивирусов нету и т.п.? из разных браузеров пробуете?

Comment: Да, телефоны чистые. Пробовал загружать с 3-ех разных телефонов: 2 андроид и 1 Айфон

Comment: Попробуйте при загрузке файла вывести print_r($_FILES); Может при загрузке файла происходит ошибка, которую вы не отлавливаете.

Ошибки в: $_FILES['file_name'][$i]['error']

Comment: Покажите сверстанную форму

Comment: При загрузке ошибок не обнаружено

Comment: модулей апача волшебных никаких не стоит? хз правда что там может быть,  но для мобильных девайсов ничего нет?

Comment: Ничего нет.....